# Why does `(c*)|(cccd)` match `ccc`, not `cccd`?

Tags: python, regex

I thought I understood Regular Expressions pretty well, but why is this matching 'ccc', not 'cccd'?

```
>>> mo = re.match('(c*)|(cccd)', 'cccd')
>>> mo.group(0)
'ccc'
```

This particular case is using Python's `re` module.

Comment: In this particular case, you can simply revert the order: `'(cccd)|(c*)'`.

Comment: The regex is evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex patterns are evaluated from left to right. Put the pattern which has higher precedence as first (*to the left of `|`*) and the lower precedence as second (*to the right of `|`*). Note that the second pattern was not allowed to match the text which was already matched by the first pattern. That is, regex engine by default won't do overlapping matches. To make the regex engine to do overlapping match then you need to put your pattern inside a capturing group and again put the capturing group inside a positive lookaround assertion (*positive lookahead and positive lookbehind*).

```
mo = re.match('(cccd)|(c*)', 'cccd')
```

Comment: Exactly, the first regex would be satisfied and thus the second would become irrelevant.

Comment: I think my confusion was with greediness and longest match.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex (`(c*)|(cccd)`) is saying match either one of two things:

1. 0 or unlimited c's
2. The literal sequence `cccd`

Because regular expressions are greedy, it consumes the `ccc` string as the match, so that is what you're returning. It will first try what ever comes first (in this case `c*`, and if it is able to make a match, then it will.

To correct to what you want, try the regex: `(cccd)|(c*)`. With this:

```
>>> mo = re.match('(cccd)|(c*)', 'cccd')
>>> mo.group(0)
'cccd'
```

Example is here: https://regex101.com/r/aU8pE7/1

Answer (score 0):

`(c*)` matches 'ccc', thus you get the match. To match "cccd", use `^(?:(c*)|(cccd))$`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wC8eB1/2).